# Odoo stays in the loading screen after report is generated

Tags: ssl, nginx, odoo, odoo-11

[image]When i click on print report, it generates the report correctly with no issues but then the page stays in the loading screen.It keeps on saying 'loading' and won't load until we refresh the browser tab manually.

i'm using odoo 11 community edition.

I tried setting web.base.url ,report.url,web.base.url.freeze and wkhtmltopdf(current version - 0.12.1.3) version upgrading.But none of it worked.

Comment: Did you check the log file ?

Comment: yes, it is also showing nothing.

Comment: Is it happen for all reports ? or a specific report only ?

Comment: POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.0" 200 -
POST /report/check_wkhtmltopdf HTTP/1.0" 200 -
GET /web/content/328594-d375662/web.report_assets_pdf.0.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -

GET /web/content/328582-06e396f/web.report_assets_common.1.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -

GET /web/content/328581-06e396f/web.report_assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -

 The PDF report has been generated for records [2180].
POST /report/download HTTP/1.0" 200 -

Comment: it is happening for all reports including the default reports.

Comment: did you have the latest version of Odoo 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196258/discussion-between-anand-mohan-and-ajmal-jk).

Comment: any updates on this issue? I having the exact same behavior.

Comment: I have the same issue, if this is solved please post the answer.

Comment: Can you post the function or action whatever you are using to print report

Comment: If the screen is stuck on the loading spinner (1) check the server log for errors (2) check the browser devtools (network and console tabs) for errors.  In particular, request responses may contain error tracebacks not reported in the server log.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with odoo13. The solution was so complicated to this issue, that it had to just be opened on a different browser (for me: I was using firefox and had to change it to chrome).

*Just change your browser to solve it.*